# Why is my main class inaccessible? (Inheritance)

Tags: c#, inheritance

I created two similar sets of code and one of them is preventing me from accessing my Base Class. I am frustrated because I cant figure out what I did differently. The main problem is that when I override the string and type return _b + _a the syntax tells me that Class1._a is unaccessible due to it protection level. I want to be able to type the following and have both variables from different classes shown but I cant because for some reason I am doing something wrong.

```
Class2 test = new Class2();
test.A = "data1 ";
test.B = "data2 ";

MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(test));
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice2222
{
    class Class1
    {
        private string _a;

        public Class1()
        {
            _a = "";
        }

        public Class1(string a)
        {
            _a = a;
        }

        public string A
        {
            get { return _a; }
            set { _a = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _a; 
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice2222
{
    class Class2 : Class1
    {
        private string _b;

        public Class2()
        {
            _b = "";
        }

        public Class2(string a, string b)
            : base(a)
        {
            _b = b;
        }

        public string B
        {
            get { return _b; }
            set { _b = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _b + _a; 
        }
    }
}
```

Code that works and is from what I can tell the same thing.
Apologies for the confusing grammar I used.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice
{
    class DadClass
    {
        private string _Kevin;
        private string _Jillian;
        private string _Bryan;

        public DadClass()
        {
            _Kevin = "";
            _Jillian = "";
            _Bryan = "";
        }

        public DadClass(string Kevin, string Jillian, string Bryan)
        {
            _Kevin = Kevin;
            _Bryan = Bryan;
            _Jillian = Jillian;
        }

        public string Kevin
        {
            get { return _Kevin; }
            set { _Kevin = value; }
        }

        public string Bryan
        {
            get { return _Bryan; }
            set { _Bryan = value; }
        }

        public string Jillian
        {
            get { return _Jillian; }
            set { _Jillian = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _Kevin + " " + _Bryan + " " + _Jillian; 
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice
{
    class ClassBruno : DadClass
    {
        private string Ack;

        public ClassBruno()
        {
            Ack = "";
        }

        public ClassBruno(string Kevin, string Jillian, string Bryan, string Acks)
            : base(Kevin, Jillian, Bryan)
        {
            Ack = Acks;
        }

        public string ACK
        {
            get{ return Ack; }
            set { Ack = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Ack + Bryan + Kevin + Jillian;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `_a` is `private` so you cannot access it from anywhere other than `Class 1`. Use `A` as that's how you are exposing `_a` outside of `Class 1` or make `_a` `protected`.

Comment: I know that I could make the classes field variables public but that is not what I am looking to do, Sorry I posted this right before I saw yours, let me look a t my code you might be right!

Comment: You shouldn't make _a public. Add a getter in the enclosing class.

Comment: If your question is what is the difference between the working code and non working code, the answer is that you are trying to access the field(one with underscore) and the working code is accessing properties (without underscore and capital first letter) inside the `ToString`.

Comment: I see I was having some confusion now, "A" is how I am exposing it outside of Class 1, So that would make sense. Also I like the idea of adding a getter in the enclosing class

Comment: You can make `_a protected` so derived classes can access it. However there are so many solutions to this problem and the fact that you didn't expect this behaviour makes me think that you should invest some more time learning about access modifiers.

Comment: Thanks for you help guys! I probably should have done a little more research but i was getting a little frustrating. Do you recommend any resources?

Answer (score 2):

The key is understanding the access modifiers.

> **public**
> The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.
>
> **private**
> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.
>
> **protected**
> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class, or in a class that is derived from that class.
>
> **internal**
> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.
>
> **protected internal**
> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly.
>
> **private protected**
> The type or member can be accessed only within its declaring assembly, by code in the same class or in a type that is derived from that class.

Source: [Access Modifiers C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Inside `Class1` you have defined:

```cs
    private string _a;
```

which means that it is ONLY accessible by the code in the same class (or struct)

However, you have also defined an accessor/mutator (getter / setter)

```cs
    public string A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; }
    }
```

So inside your `Class2` (incorrect code)

```cs
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _b + _a; 
    }
```

you are trying to access a private field, instead of accessing it via the public accessor you have created (corrected code)

```cs
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _b + A; // note the 'A' (property to access) rather than '_a' (private field)
    }
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to include the `A` property publically in your base class, you could change the access modifier of _a to be protected, and then it would be accessible in `Class2` (because it is derived from `Class1`).

#### Edit:

Also note, because you have not provided (explicitly) access modifiers to your classes (`class Class1 { ... }`) the class itself defaults to `internal`, which is important if you are trying to access the class itself across multiple assemblies. (I realize by the question that this is beyond your current level of learning, but something to keep in mind down the road)